# Helios unable to install Maven plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, helios

I am using **Helios Service Release 2** and I am trying to install maven plugin to create new Maven project. But when trying to install maven using ***http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases*** I am getting below exception

```
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
     Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes 
     Incubating components) 1.8.1.20170728-1531 
       (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.8.1.20170728-1531)
       Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.8.1.20170728-
         1531 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.8.1.20170728-1531) requires 'bundle 
         org.eclipse.osgi 3.10.0' but it could not be found
          Cannot satisfy dependency:
           From: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.8.1.20170728-1531 
         (org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui 1.8.1.20170728-1531)
To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.8.1,1.9.0)
   Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 
 1.8.1.20170728-1531 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.8.1.20170728-1531)
To: org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui [1.8.1.20170728-1531]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the latest Orbit site to your update site :

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20170516192513/repository/

and then make the upgrade.